# Как одновременно менять масштаб в нескольких ChartArea?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `Chart` контрол на WinForms. На нем есть несколько `ChartArea`. Для каждой из них получается сделать масштабирование

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true; 

chart1.ChartAreas[1].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[1].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true; 
chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
```

Можно ли сделать так чтобы масштабируя одну область, вторая масштабировалась так же?

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? Если вы знаете как масштабировать одну область, то просто изменяйте их одновременно. Если это происходит в обработчике события для каждой области отдельно, то просто подпишите один обработчик с объединенным кодом на оба события сразу.

Comment: Я выделяю мышью область и она масштабируется. Что мне надо дальше использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть встроенная возможность синхронизировать несколько `ChartArea`. За это отвечает свойство [`ChartArea.AlignWithChartArea`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.alignwithchartarea). Правда, я не уверен, касается ли это масштаба.
Попробуйте сделать так:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name = "area0";
chart1.ChartAreas[1].AlignWithChartArea = "area0";
```

Comment: да,масштабирование получилось, спасибо. буду смотреть как поведут себя остальные свойства при масштабе.

Comment: поменяв тип по оси х на time, масштабирование перестало работать. может что то надо донастроить?

Comment: @Arkadiy Как именно вы поменяли тип оси? Если при помощи свойства [`Axis.IntervalType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.intervaltype(v=vs.110).aspx), то сказано: _Если тип интервала оси представлен временем в виде часов, минут и т.п., то, чтобы изменение масштаба работало правильно, для свойства `IntervalType` должно также быть установлено значение времени. Например, если `AxisX.IntervalType` задан в часах, то можно задать `CursorX.IntervalType` в минутах._

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, сработало.

Comment: @Arkadiy Если ответ решает вашу проблему, отметьте его как ["принятый"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Подробнее: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)